# Calling an app from within my app does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have the following code:

```
NSString *customURL = @"photo://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:customURL];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}
else
{
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
     delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
    otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}
```

Which is trying to open iPhoto app by using the custom URL. But the code returns error message and iPhoto is not launched. Any idea why this is?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`photo://` doesn't seem to be a supported url.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1

Comment: Thank you for your input. Just as a matter of interest, what do you think of using AppleScript as a workaround? Will it work? I am not familiar with AppleScript, but if it can do the trick I will certainly dig deeper into the topic.

Comment: iOS does not support AppleScript